# Traversing File Directory

Tags: python, file, traversal

this is the first question I am posting on stackoverflow so excuse me if I did something out of the norm.

I am trying to create a python program which traverses a user selected directory to display all file contents of the folders selected. For example: Documents folders has several folders with files inside of them, I am trying to save all files in the Documents folder to an array.

The method below is what I am using to traverse a directory (hoping it is a simple problem)

```
def saveFilesToArray(dir):
allFiles = []

os.chdir(dir)
for file in glob.glob("*"):
    print(file)
    if (os.path.isfile(file)):
        allFiles.append(file)
    elif(os.path.isdir(file)):
        print(dir + "/" + file + " is a directory")
        allFiles.append(saveFilesToArray(dir + "/" + file))
return allFiles
```

Comment: What problem are you facing?

Comment: Sorry, didn't add my question. When I run this code on a directory with more than one directory within it, the program begins to consider directories as files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give you just the files:

```
import os
def list_files(root):
    all_files = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(root, followlinks=True):
        for file in files:
            full_path = os.path.join(root, file)
            all_files.append(full_path)
    return all_files
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is helpful:

```
import os
def saveFilesToList(theDir):
    allFiles = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(theDir):
        for name in files:
            npath = os.path.join(root,name)
            if os.path.isfile(npath):
                allFiles.append(npath)
    return allFiles
```

Traverses all directories and stores the path to files (that are not directories) in the list. It seems much easier to use this than glob.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. And I see why my previous code wasn't working too